# Cisco ASA - Juniper VPN tunnel not sending traffic

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, firewall

Cisco ASA has following Config, the tunnel shows active but doesn't send any traffic. Please help me.

configuration.

```
access-list outside_cryptomap_1 line 1 extended permit ip object LAN_Subnet object Remote_Site_A 

      group-policy GroupPolicy_<RemoteWAN_IP> internal
      group-policy GroupPolicy_<RemoteWAN_IP> attributes
        vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1
      exit
      tunnel-group <RemoteWAN_IP> type ipsec-l2l
      tunnel-group <RemoteWAN_IP> general-attributes
        default-group-policy GroupPolicy_<RemoteWAN_IP>
      tunnel-group <RemoteWAN_IP> ipsec-attributes
        ikev1 pre-shared-key **********
        isakmp keepalive threshold 10 retry 2
      crypto map WAN_map 1 match address outside_cryptomap_1
      crypto map WAN_map 1 set  peer  <RemoteWAN_IP>
      crypto map WAN_map 1 set  ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-251-MD5
```

---

running config

```
access-list outside_cryptomap_1 extended permit ip object LocalLAN_subnet object RemoteLAN_subnet 
nat (inside,outside) source static LocalLAN_subnet LocalLAN_subnet destination static RemoteLAN_subnet RemoteLAN_subnet no-proxy-arp route-lookup
crypto map outside_map 1 match address outside_cryptomap_1
crypto map outside_map 1 set peer <<RemoteWAN_IP>>
crypto map outside_map 1 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-251-MD5 
crypto map outside_map 1 set security-association lifetime seconds 3100
crypto map outside_map 1 set security-association lifetime kilobytes 2147483147
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto isakmp nat-traversal 3100
group-policy GroupPolicy_<<RemoteWAN_IP>> internal
group-policy GroupPolicy_<<RemoteWAN_IP>> attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1
isakmp keepalive threshold 10 retry 3
tunnel-group <<RemoteWAN_IP>> type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group <<RemoteWAN_IP>> general-attributes
 default-group-policy GroupPolicy_<<RemoteWAN_IP>>
tunnel-group <<RemoteWAN_IP>> ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
 inspect icmp
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is not quite enough information here to provide an answer and Stack exchange really discourages answering questions that leave much to the imagination.

Still there are some tools I might as well pass along that may be helpful for you. For one we need to determine if a phase 1 SA is ever even established.

Here are some commands I run frequently to troubleshoot tunnels

```
show crypto isakmp sa
```

If that looks clean(active) run some debugs to see where things might be getting stuck. During your debugs send **interesting** traffic and observe the log messages.

First) `Debug crypto isakmp`

If you can't find an answer there then **undebug all** and

Second) `debug crypto ipsec`

I've successfully setup tunnels with Juniper(ScreenOS) in the past but they generally ran best over GRE as the tunneling protocol.